# redirection in htaccess file

Tags: 7, redirection, .htaccess

I'm working on Drupal7.

I want to redirect all the URl's to external domain except some.
Below rewrite I have added in .htaccess file and its working fine.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/user.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/testurl.*$
RewriteRule .* https://abcxyz.com [R=301,L]
```

But then, homepage also redirecting to https://abcxyz.com

How to stop homepage redirection or how to add homepage in the exclude list like user, testurl?

I have tried below to exclude the homepage in the redirection.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/homepage$
```

But nothing worked.

Can you help me on this please?

Comment: This is more an Apache question than a Drupal one, but try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$` (i.e. exclude when the first character is `/` followed by end of line)

Comment: I tried this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ but not worked

Comment: I just verified that `!^/$` works on my dev Drupal 7. Perhaps there is a RewriteRule before yours that conflicts with it. Is it located immediately after the `RewriteEngine on` directive? Is there a `RewriteRule` in your `<VirtualHost>` or `<Directory>` directive? Maybe using a permanent redirect (`301`) before you had the correct condition causes your browser's cache to redirect without contacting the server again. Change your rewrite rule to use a temporary redirect: `[R=302,L]`, and use incognito/private mode for testing. By the way closing all incognito mode windows should clear its cache.

Comment: Got the result. In the rewriterule, insted of *, need to add + symbol which is the domain url.  RewriteRule (.+) https://abcxyz.com [R=302,L]
So, now domain, I mean homepage is not redirecting :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem migrating to a new domain but needed to keep the services endpoints active on old domain since they were externally active. The key was including a RewriteCond for index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/services/active/endpoint$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%{ENV:protossl}://new-domain/$1 [L,R=301]
```